# CompareValidator issue on Firefox

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-3.5

I need to validate a date in a web forms application. For this I use a CompareValidator with

```
Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Date"
```

The problem is that this Validator doesn't work properly on Firefox with 2 digit years. ( javascript error: **m[2] is undefined**)
With a 4 digits year it's working properly.

This problem is described also here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/355573/comparevalidator-client-side-bug-two-digit-year-in-mozilla-based-browsers-throws-js-exception

Does anyone know a nice workaround for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to create a date validator which inherits from `BaseValidator` and overwrites the `ControlPropertiesValid(), EvaluateIsValid() and OnPreRender(EventArgs e)`.
If you have other ideas please shot.

Comment: I don't understand why don't you post your solution to your own question... It's valuable to share.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in ASP.NET 3.5 and earlier, in the client-side validation script. (The script works correctly in older versions of Internet Explorer but not in newer standards-compliant browsers.)

Microsoft has fixed the bug in ASP.NET 4.0.

If you cannot upgrade to ASP.NET 4.0, you can export the WebUIValidation.js resource from the version of System.Web.dll that comes with .NET 4.0, and then register the script in your page's `PreRender` event:

```
this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(
    typeof(System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator), "WebUIValidation.js",
    "url-to-the-4.0-WebUIValidation.js-script");
```

Alternately, you can override the buggy `ValidatorConvert` function by adding the following to a `<script type="text/javascript">` block on your page:

```
function ValidatorConvert(op, dataType, val) {
    function GetFullYear(year) {
        var twoDigitCutoffYear = val.cutoffyear % 100;
        var cutoffYearCentury = val.cutoffyear - twoDigitCutoffYear;
        return ((year > twoDigitCutoffYear) ? (cutoffYearCentury - 100 + year) : (cutoffYearCentury + year));
    }
    var num, cleanInput, m, exp;
    if (dataType == "Integer") {
        exp = /^\s*[-\+]?\d+\s*$/;
        if (op.match(exp) == null)
            return null;
        num = parseInt(op, 10);
        return (isNaN(num) ? null : num);
    }
    else if(dataType == "Double") {
        exp = new RegExp("^\\s*([-\\+])?(\\d*)\\" + val.decimalchar + "?(\\d*)\\s*$");
        m = op.match(exp);
        if (m == null)
            return null;
        if (m[2].length == 0 && m[3].length == 0)
            return null;
        cleanInput = (m[1] != null ? m[1] : "") + (m[2].length>0 ? m[2] : "0") + (m[3].length>0 ? "." + m[3] : "");
        num = parseFloat(cleanInput);
        return (isNaN(num) ? null : num);
    }
    else if (dataType == "Currency") {
        var hasDigits = (val.digits > 0);
        var beginGroupSize, subsequentGroupSize;
        var groupSizeNum = parseInt(val.groupsize, 10);
        if (!isNaN(groupSizeNum) && groupSizeNum > 0) {
            beginGroupSize = "{1," + groupSizeNum + "}";
            subsequentGroupSize = "{" + groupSizeNum + "}";
        }
        else {
            beginGroupSize = subsequentGroupSize = "+";
        }
        exp = new RegExp("^\\s*([-\\+])?((\\d" + beginGroupSize + "(\\" + val.groupchar + "\\d" + subsequentGroupSize + ")+)|\\d*)"
                        + (hasDigits ? "\\" + val.decimalchar + "?(\\d{0," + val.digits + "})" : "")
                        + "\\s*$");
        m = op.match(exp);
        if (m == null)
            return null;
        if (m[2].length == 0 && hasDigits && m[5].length == 0)
            return null;
        cleanInput = (m[1] != null ? m[1] : "") + m[2].replace(new RegExp("(\\" + val.groupchar + ")", "g"), "") + ((hasDigits && m[5].length > 0) ? "." + m[5] : "");
        num = parseFloat(cleanInput);
        return (isNaN(num) ? null : num);
    }
    else if (dataType == "Date") {
        var yearFirstExp = new RegExp("^\\s*((\\d{4})|(\\d{2}))([-/]|\\. ?)(\\d{1,2})\\4(\\d{1,2})\\.?\\s*$");
        m = op.match(yearFirstExp);
        var day, month, year;
        if (m != null && (((typeof(m[2]) != "undefined") && (m[2].length == 4)) || val.dateorder == "ymd")) {
            day = m[6];
            month = m[5];
            year = (m[2].length == 4) ? m[2] : GetFullYear(parseInt(m[3], 10));
        }
        else {
            if (val.dateorder == "ymd"){
                return null;
            }
            var yearLastExp = new RegExp("^\\s*(\\d{1,2})([-/]|\\. ?)(\\d{1,2})(?:\\s|\\2)((\\d{4})|(\\d{2}))(?:\\s\u0433\\.|\\.)?\\s*$");
            m = op.match(yearLastExp);
            if (m == null) {
                return null;
            }
            if (val.dateorder == "mdy") {
                day = m[3];
                month = m[1];
            }
            else {
                day = m[1];
                month = m[3];
            }
            year = ((typeof(m[5]) != "undefined") && (m[5].length == 4)) ? m[5] : GetFullYear(parseInt(m[6], 10));
        }
        month -= 1;
        var date = new Date(year, month, day);
        if (year < 100) {
            date.setFullYear(year);
        }
        return (typeof(date) == "object" && year == date.getFullYear() && month == date.getMonth() && day == date.getDate()) ? date.valueOf() : null;
    }
    else {
        return op.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using ASP.NET 4.0 with ie9 or later and still getting the JS error when entering two digit dates.  I'm surprised there is not more posts on it.

Comment: @pghcpa: Look at the validation script in your browser's developer tools. Do you see references to `"undefined"` in the `ValidatorConvert` function?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this helps you(last post,  only dataType == "Date" needed), but i havent tested it:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1358621.aspx

Comment: Hi Tim thank for your hint. In the thread you specified Rachel suggested to use a CustomValidator with a fixed java-script code from ComparedValidator. I preferred to create a new validator since I can easily reuse it through the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom validator

```
Imports System.Globalization

  Private Sub CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(source As Object, args As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs) Handles CustomValidator1.ServerValidate
    Dim dateResult As Date
    If Date.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("zh-CN"), DateTimeStyles.None, dateResult) Then
        args.IsValid = True
    Else
        args.IsValid = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Could do the equivalent with on client-side in JS if preferred.