# CompareValidtor Date type throw a Javascript error with 2 digits year

Tags: asp.net, date, validation

I have following controls in my asp page,

```
Date: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="TextBox1_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBox1" ClearTime="True"></asp:CalendarExtender>
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Wrong!" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Date" CultureInvariantValues="True" > </asp:CompareValidator>
```

If I put a date 01/24/12, I got an JavaScript error,

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property
>   'length': object is null or undefined. It was threw by the function
>   ValidatorConvert(...).

I checked the local variable m, m[5] is missing. I googled the problem, looks like it was a bug in the javascript function ValidatorConvert. Someone fixed the function, but can someone tell me how to replace/override the default one?

Thanks.

Also I wonder if anyone has the same problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CompareValidator issue on Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021526/comparevalidator-issue-on-firefox)